# How to use verbs to list actions in a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, formality

How should I use verbs to list actions in a sentence?

I wrote the following sentence:

> "The learner can search content of the book, take a book from electronic library, and discuss with the classmate."

I confuse that is above sentence correct and formal?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the pattern "L can X, Y, and Z" - I think that's the main point of your question. (The grammaticality and/or formality of the sentence is another issue.) Apart from that, I'd like to suggest improving your question by trying not to phrase it as a proofreading request, which is [off-topic](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site.

Comment: The use of articles is kind of strange and inconsistent.  I would say search *the* content of the book (or maybe "books"), take a book from *the* electronic library, and discuss with *a* classmate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I can't say it's formal. Although it does make sense, I believe there's something wrong with the logical and orderly and consistent relation of parts. If you are trying to talk about the benefits and advantages of ebooks, then in that case it would be wise to start by saying:

> Ebooks present many benefits and advantages. They are searchable. Learners can easily check out library books on their e-reader, search for any information in an eBook, purchase (or download) them, and start discussing them with their classmates.

Comment: Thank Mia. I told about the remote learning via computer.